# Questions about writing applications vs Belongs to StackOverflow in Vote to Close

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

There seems to be little differentiation between these two:

- it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate... > off-topic because... > Questions about writing and publishing Android apps..
- it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate... > off-topic because... > This question belongs to another site in the Stack Exchange network > StackOverflow

Most of the times, I see programming questions being flagged with the first reason. It is my understanding that the 1st reason covers:

- publishing Android apps
- Market-related questions, from a developer perspective
- other topics that are primarily of concern to developers

Therefore, we could consider the following as programming, and be moved to StackOverflow:

- writing Android apps
- writing custom ROMs

Given that StackOverflow has a lot of reviewers, it shouldn't be a problem if we migrated questions that may have been off-topic to them. Anyhow, programming questions should go there, instead of being flagged with the first reason.

Or, is there any other way we could improve this?

Comment: Many of the programming-related questions that I see and vote to close, just don't seem to be good enough questions to be worth migrating. It's not a matter of if they're on-or-off-topic for SO, more that they're just bad questions that happen to have programming content in them. Normally a total lack of details about what's happening, what should be happening and what they've tried.

Comment: What GAThrawm and Al Everett said. 90% of the programming questions asked here are crap. But this also means that there are 10% that deserve migration to stackoverflow. That's how I deal with them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on GAThrawn's comment...

The first rule of migration is:

> Don't migrate crap.

Migration should be reserved for *outstanding* questions that *just happen to be on the wrong site*. Migration should be the exception, not the rule.

The *vast* majority of development questions we see are not very good. Were we to migrate them to Stack Overflow anyway, they would be quickly downvoted and closed. That's not helpful to anyone and now twice as many people have had to "handle" this really bad question.

Further, a significant portion of the development questions we get here aren't on-topic for Stack Overflow anyway. "How do I get started in Android development" for instance, or "what's wrong with my developer account on the Play Store" are all development "problems" that have no place anywhere in the Stack Exchange network.

So, while I think it can be worthwhile to ensure we get clear and helpful wording for our off-topic closures, we should keep the "Android development" closure reason.

Comment: This. We don't want to shovel our crap to another site, the same way we don't want their crap.